# Avoid Spinner's onItemSelected being called automatically after setAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

The `Spinner` is calling `onItemSelected` automatically after setting adapter, and I'd like to avoid it without any kind of workaround such as using flags to check if it's the first time; add the listener after setting adapter or any verification like those.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do that?

Comment: does it harm your logic or creating some problem?

Comment: you want something that is not necessary, and there for does not have to exist. Correct solution is set listener after setting adapter as for me.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed both. It harms my logic which triggers an issue.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Spinner uses a `pendingNotification` variable which calls the `onItemSelected` even if I set listener after setting adapter. Besides, I need to feed the spinner many times in different steps, which means I'd have to remove and add spinner's listener every time. I'd cause bad performance :(

Comment: they made it on purpose and what you want to do is a workaround

Comment: @pskink If what I wanna do is a workaround, what would you do if you have an action into `onItemSelected` and it can't be executed at the first time?

Comment: Did you find the solution?, cause I've also the same problem

Comment: @ParagPawar Actually it always does by nature. You can't change it. However, you can deal with it into your listener. Every time your listener is called, you check it if the position is different. If it's the same, it means it can be the first time or the user is simply selecting the same item, so you dont need to do anything.

Comment: Yeah, I solved it by using a famous workaround for it, the flag :p
I checked it in the listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, add one item at first position(at zero index) and then add your actual items in array(array list) and in getView() method (), check for the first position (it means o index) set height for that item to 0. I hope it will help you out.

Comment: I'd like a simple solution. That's a workaround and I want to avoid it.

Comment: I have also faced similar situation and could not find any proper solution .I used this work around. If you found proper solution please must update me as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Following worked for me,

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelected(false);  // otherwise listener will be called on initialization
spinner.setSelection(0,true);  // otherwise listener will be called on initialization
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    .. listener code 
}
```

Please note the order is important. I hope that helped.

Comment: I set listeners only once and set selection many times in different parts of my code. So this solution will just deal with the first `setSelection`.

Comment: @Lennon I hope you tried the code, please use spinner.setSelection(0,true); where you are setting your listener once. That will solve your problem of avoiding the unwanted call to onItemSelected. Afterwards you are free to use setSelection as you like, it will not harm.